# Error 2 Creation of data source "A"."B" failed: ERROR: relation "B" already exist

Tags: table, pgadmin-3

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

Foolish question from a newbie perhaps but as I reckon it may be the code for table "B" that I created, how do I edit the code in pgAdmin3?

The key aim of this is to migrate data from one table in MapInfo into an existing table with a completely different table structure in QGIS.

code for current table below:

```
-- Table: A."B"

-- DROP TABLE A."B";

CREATE TABLE A."B"
(
  "UID" integer NOT NULL,
  roadname character varying(100),
  CONSTRAINT tmp_ga2_pk PRIMARY KEY ("UID")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE A."B"
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 0):

when you drop table B if there are any objects depending on it, by default it won't be dropped unlees you mention `CASCADE`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B CASCADE;
```

maybe this is where it blocks